# Jenkins Pipeline check if parameterized build is really parameterized

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Currently i am working with Jenkins pipelines and parameterized builds.

I know i can start a pipeline stage where i can check if the given parameters are empty or not, but is there another way how to check if a parameterized build is really parameterized?

Like a step before i go into stages?
A stage where we can check some conditions before going into the stages.

Comment: You can use `when { expression { params.skipTests != "Yes" } }`, `script` block in stage, or `return` some variables and use it in next stages validation. Specify please, what You want to achieve.

Comment: Jenkins Pipelines works with stages , but before entering the first stage , i want to run a block where i can test if the parameters are not invalid,i would like to know how this could be achieved in a Pipeline script, my approach was to create another stage and check the conditions in that stage but i would like to know for future pipeline scrips , if there is a method to do some precheck things before entering the first stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Declarative Pipeline where is no way run something 'before'. You can run another job which trigger 'the job' or try something like this, if some parameters not pass validation whole job will be aborted. But You can control that in `script` block.

```
def ex(param){
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    error('BAD PARAM: ' + param)
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    parameters {
        choice(name: 'a', choices:"NO\nOK\nMaybe", description: "Tests?" )
        choice(name: 'b', choices:"NO\nOK\nMaybe", description: "Tests?" )
        choice(name: 'c', choices:"NO\nOK\nMaybe", description: "Tests?" )
        choice(name: 'd', choices:"NO\nOK\nMaybe", description: "Tests?" )
    }   

    stages { 
        stage("check params") {
            steps {
                script {
                    //make some crazy validation
                    if ("${params.a}" != "OK") {ex("a")}
                    if ("${params.b}" != "OK") {ex("b")}
                    if ("${params.c}" != "OK") {ex("c")}
                    if ("${params.d}" != "OK") {ex("d")}
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Next stage") {
            steps {
                echo "Run"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can also use `params.each` to check if any parameter "choices" is `null` or empty string `""` or are not the value is should be like "OK" etc...

Useful when parameters are passed from another job, and a variable or method is used which happened to not have an acceptable value:

```
build job: "some-jobname",
        parameters: [
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'a', value: thisMethodReturnsOK()],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'b', value: oopsThisMethodReturnsEmptySTRING()],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'c', value: oopsThisMethodReturnsNULL()],
                [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'd', value: oopsThisVariableContainsUnacceptableVALUE],
                           ]
```

---

This modified version will validate each available build parameter and cause an `ABORT` if parameter is `BAD`:

```
# Job: "some-jobname"

def ex(param){
    currentBuild.result = 'ABORTED'
    error('BAD PARAM: ' + param)
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    testA = param.a
    testB = param.b
    testC = param.c
    testD = param.d

    stages { 
        stage("check params") {
            steps {
                script {
                    params.each {
                        if (it == null || it == "" || it != "OK")
                            ex(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Next stage") {
            steps {
                echo "Run and use parameters passed to TestA etc..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```